# Watch with props Vue3

Tags: date, vuejs3, watch

I want to try update modelValue and chang value in datepicker

```
watch(range, (range) => {
  emit("update:modelValue", range);
  console.log("update:modelValue", range)
  
});
watch(() => props.modelValue,
  (modelValue) => {
    range.value = {
      start: modelValue.start,
      end: modelValue.end,
    };
  }
);
```

is working but is delay and show error [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you need the first watch?

```
watch(() => props.modelValue,
  (modelValue) => {
    // Maybe some if condition check to avoid unnecessary calls
    range.value = {
      start: modelValue.start,
      end: modelValue.end,
    };
    emit("update:modelValue", range);
  }
);
```